# Cannot add Stack Exchange OpenID login

Tags: support, login, accounts

I've always used a Yahoo OpenID acount to login to Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites. Now I'd like to get rid of it so I created a new OpenID at https://openid.stackexchange.com. However, I cannot get it added as login for Stack Overflow. Here are some print screens of what goes on. Being logged in to Stack Overflow, I visit https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add?returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent:

[image]

Hmm, no Stack Exchange OpenID option there? No problem, manually enter https://openid.stackexchange.com and click `Submit` which gets the Stack Exchange OpenID login page:

[image]

After logging in, everything seems just fine since I'm presented the option to add the login:

[image]

After clicking `Confirm` it takes me back to my main profile page. And the history on the Stack Exchange OpenID sit indeed shows `Authenticated to stackoverflow.com`. However when clicking the `my logins` link on my profile page it still only shows my original Yahoo OpenID, and it does indeed seem to be the only one cause when I try to delete it, it tells me it cannot do that because it is my only login.

So how do I properly add the Stack Exchange OpenID as my only login for Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites, keeping my current account?

Comment: linked https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297767/cant-add-new-stack-exchange-openid-login?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you are logged in to the Stack Exchange OpenId provider, you can use your own URL to login. Click the link:

[image: Use your own URL to log in]

You will get a couple of `link` elements you can use. You want to pick the second URL

```
<link rel="openid2.local_id" 
              href="https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/{some-guid-here}">
```

You can paste that HREF directly in the "manually enter your OpenId" box in the add-login page.

> [image: manually enter your OpenId]

Comment: I actually tried this already (sorry, should have mentioned that), but no avail

Comment: @stijn - will have to investigate further then. The above should work. Have you completed the Stack Exchange OpenId registration (should have gotten an email)?

Comment: hmm, sort of - I was following the steps desribed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704 and got the Account Recovery email, entered a password in the supplied link which apparently did create the SE OpenID account since I can login to it.

Comment: OK. What happened is that an account merge between your existing account and the new OpenId was pending manual approval, since you are a high rep user (partially also due to different email addresses being used). I've gone through and approved the merge, so all should be well now, @stijn.