# Change Stack Exchange login email

Tags: support, login

I have a question similar to [Cannot add Stack Exchange OpenID login](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255394/cannot-add-stack-exchange-openid-login), but there is still something I do not understand.

I am presently logging into Stack Overflow using email address `A`. This is my login userID with Stack Overlow. Due to life changes, I will soon lose access to this email address.

How can I register email address `B` (on a domain that I own) and switch to logging in via that address?

(Actually, I don't care if email address `A` remains my loginID... just so long as the actual email address `A` itself is no longer associated with my account, replaced by email address `B`.)

I do not wish to login via Facebook, or Google, or etc. Only with my own domain. Is this still possible?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I change the email address associated with my Stack Exchange OpenID?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102392/how-do-i-change-the-email-address-associated-with-my-stack-exchange-openid) on MSE.

Answer (score 5):

#### OpenID is being phased out

You can [add a new login at this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add) and [manage your logins here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current#).

If you want to change your email: https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current

Comment: Keeping this for future reference.

Comment: For whatever reason, the "add a new login" method doesn't work for me - I enter a new email/pwd and it says they are invalid. Pulling my hair out here. This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that there already was an answer to this question, however my pre-question searching did not uncover it.

Link is here: [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704)

Arjan's link in the comments lead to another comment by vurquee who linked to the answer above.

Via the instructions given, I was able to create a second Stack Exchange OpenID associated with my account, which allowed me to remove the initial OpenID that was associated with the old email address. A bit convoluted, but so long as it worked all is well.

Thanks for your post, Anna Lear. Through the answer posted above I was able to create that 2nd OpenID, which you observed, and I can now remove the old OpenID/email account.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have two Stack Exchange OpenIDs associated with your Stack Overflow profile. You can remove the one you no longer wish to use by going to your profile, clicking "my logins", and then "remove".

Follow this up with an message to us via the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to have us delete that OpenID since presumably you'll never need it again.