# How do I change my Stack Overflow account so it's not Facebook authenticated?

Tags: support, login

I created my account a while ago and selected to log in using Facebook. This worked well.

Several months ago my company decided to block access to Facebook and now I am no longer able to access my Stack Overflow account.

How can I change the way that I log into my account so that I can access it when I'm at work?

Comment: related/dup? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269758/stack-exchange-login-change-to-a-different-email-id and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258540/change-stack-exchange-login-email

Comment: or [this one on the uber meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)